# Can I use variables in XML files?

Tags: xml

Is it possible to define variables in an XML file?

For example:

`VARIABLE = 'CHIEF_NAME'`

```xml
    <foods>
      <food>
        <name>French Toast</name>
        <price>$4.50</price>
        <calories>600</calories>
        <chief>VARIABLE</chief>
      </food>
      <food>
        <name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
        <price>$6.95</price>
        <calories>950</calories>
        <chief>VARIABLE</chief>
      </food>
    </foods>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can declare an [**entity reference**](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-references) for `chief` and reference it as `&chief;`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE foods [
  <!ENTITY chief "CHIEF_NAME!">
  <!-- .... -->
]>
<foods>
  <food>
    <name>French Toast</name>
    <price>$4.50</price>
    <calories>600</calories>
    <chief>&chief;</chief>
  </food>
  <food>
    <name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
    <price>$6.95</price>
    <calories>950</calories>
    <chief>&chief;</chief>
  </food>
</foods>
```

Comment: How do you change this for the dynamic values coming from an API.

Comment: XML provides the above notion of setting a "variable" (entity) value in one location and using it in multiple places.  It does not provide the notion of then opening *that* setting to an API of any sort; your application would have to re-write the entity value directly or indirectly through system entity.

Answer (score 0):

Thats what XSLT is for.

[XSLT Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT)

Something to get you started:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:variable name="yourVar" select="'CHIEF_NAME'">
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <food>
    <name>French Toast</name>
    <price>$4.50</price>
    <calories>600</calories>
    <chief><xsl:copy-of select="$yourVar" /></chief>
  </food>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This syntax is not exactly correct, but I think generally this is the direction you should seek