# In XSD, is it possible to define the value of maxOccurs by a variable?

Tags: xml, xsd

For example, I have the following XSD line:

```
<xs:element name="child_name" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="10"/>
```

The `child_name` tag is maxed to have `10` instances. Is it possible to have that `10` referred as some sort of variable and then defined it elsewhere? (The following code **not legit**, but just showing if possible to have something like `some_variable`, and then have `some_variable` defined elsewhere?)

```
<xs:element name="child_name" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="some_variable"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, **`element/@maxOccurs`** [**may only**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-element) be a [nonNegativeInteger](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/datatypes.html#nonNegativeInteger) or `unbounded`.

There are no provisions for allowing it to be a variable, nor are there provisions for declaring or setting variables.

These probably aren't the sort of XSD-level support you're seeking, but here are a couple work-around alternatives:

1. [Use an entity reference at the XML level as a sort of variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777149/can-i-use-variables-in-xml-files).
2. Compose/rewrite the XSD dynamically such as via XSLT to vary the
   value of `element/@maxOccurs`.