# XML: What is the proper way to reference a node in another line?

Tags: xml, reference, nodes

Suppose I have something like this:

```
<Program>
    <versionName>client</versionName>
    <shortcutName>Shortcut to versionName</shortcutName>
</Program>
```

Except when I read it in C# it should say "Shortcut to client" but it instead says "Shortcut to versionName". I tried using

```
<shortcutName>Shortcut to <versionName>client</versionName></shortcutName>
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference one element from another via `id` and `idref` attributes, but that's not going to give the sort of substitution effect you're describing. See **[Can I use variables in XML files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34777149/290085)** for how to use entity references as a form of variable binding for about as close as you can get without writing code to achieve the reference/substitution effect you seek.