# How to assign XML DTD entity to attribute value

Tags: xml, dtd, xxe, dtd-parsing

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Input [  
    <!ELEMENT Input ANY >
    <!ENTITY xxe SYSTEM "file:///c:/test.txt" >]>
<ExecutionParameters>
  <Inputs>
    <Input Name="Input1" Value="VALUE_OF_XXE"></Input>
  </Inputs>
</ExecutionParameters>
```

I want to pass xxe (content of test.txt file) to the VALUE_OF_XXE.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot reference an *external* entity from an XML *attribute* value; this is **not allowed**:

```
<Input Name="Input1" Value="&xxe;"></Input>
```

### Alternatives

1. Reference the external entity from an *element* value:

   ```
   <Input Name="Input1" Value="">&xxe;</Input>
   ```
2. Reference an *internal* entity from an attribute value:

   ```
    <!ENTITY xie "Some text here" >]>
   ```

### See also

- [Can I use variables in XML files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34777149/290085)